# why jupyter notebook not working in Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I get this error message all the time when i want to open jupyter notebook . I really appreciate if i get a help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NP\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\NP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: I run it on Anaconda Powershell prompt

Comment: What command(s) did you execute? Can you share the particular script you're trying to open?

Comment: I just first installed Anaconda then went over to  Its  Powershell and just typed "Jupyter notebook"but  i had this problem

Comment: _I just first installed Anaconda then went over to Its Powershell and just typed "Jupyter notebook"but i had this problem_ So was that in the base environment?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first time opening it up? If so, then you must have done something wrong in the installation. Try uninstalling and reinstalling properly or use google colab.
I actually stopped using jupyter notebook and started using google colab instead. It's much better, stores code in your google drive, you get free GPUs/TPUs and module installation is really easy and is a good alternative if you are unable to fix this.

Comment: Hey Amay, What is This Google Colab .has a same functionality as Jupyter ? Thank you for the help by the way. I appreciate it

Comment: Google colab is the same as Jupyter. It supports .ipynb files as well and most functions are the same. It's just that Jupyter notebook is local and you have to install it and everything and colab is cloud based. Your code gets saved in the google drive and no installation is needed. Just click on this link and start coding-https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: And you also get free GPUs and TPUs

Answer (score 0):

You must have the same problem as stated here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435

It should be conflicts made by conda and/or pip.

Try:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Comment: Thank you Niel , But still doesnt work.. I had to use this on shell
python -m notebook